# Binding Strings to Drop Down List

Tags: c#, linq, binding

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mmsdata>
 <timestamp>Fri Jan 30 08:46:13 EST 2015</timestamp>
 <mill n="AG" name="Augusta, GA">
  <ds>
   <server>agppra</server>
   <server>agpprb</server>
  </ds>
  <mach n="1">
   <srn n="1" calctype="2CV">RL.CLP (1)</srn>
```

Can anyone see the error in this code that keeps it from binding to the dropdownlist1? I reused code that worked for binding an int to the dropdownlist2, but this one will not bind anything. If you can't see an error, maybe guided help as to where I should be looking?

```html
// Getting the XML file imported in
string filePath = @"C:\Projects\MEAS\Central\MillView\PVDA\Main\PVDA\PVDA.Web\MillData.xml";
// Set the file path
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);


var dropDownDataList1 = GetMillInfo(xDoc, "AG");

// Bind your Mills to your DropDownList1
DropDownList1.DataSource = GetMillInfo(xDoc, "AG");
// Set your text / value properties
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "millName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "millInfo";
// Actually bind the contents to be reflected in the UI
DropDownList1.DataBind();

public List<Mill> GetMillInfo(XDocument xDoc, string millNameInfo)
{
 return xDoc.XPathSelectElements("./mmsdata/mill")
     .Where(x => x.Attribute("n").Value == millNameInfo)
     .Elements()
     .Select(x => new Mill
     {
      millInfo = x.Value,
      millName = x.Attribute("n").Value
     }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Start with *"does your list actually contain any elements?"*

Comment: Let me add a snippet of the XML. I am looking for the attributes

Comment: Jordan, it looks like you are not getting any data because you are calling the GetMillInfo(xDoc, " ") with no value.  That means that you only get data where n is equal to a space (" ").  Change the (" ") argument to one of the n values.

Comment: Made adjustments, and according to my XML I should add "AG" in the empty (" "), I did that, and still receive an NullException thrown. Also got rid of where I made millNameInfo.ToString() as this was redundant because I already specified that it was a string